# ActiveX control with multiple classes

Tags: activex

Currently I have an activex control and I registered it to my computer with regsvr32 foo.dll. 
(NOTE: This is a third party activex control so I do not actually have the source code for it, just a dll)

When I pull up regedit under the classes I see my dll registered, however it has multiple classes.  Foo.class1, Foo.class2 and each one of these classes has there own clsid.  When I try and embed this activex control into an html page there is no clsid for the entire control only the clsids for each class.  What is the best way to embed this control to have use of its functions.

The company told me to create an activex control and put there activex control inside it.  I have been searching the internet but have no idea on how to do that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Thanks

EDIT:
All avenues with the company have been exhausted.  There answer to us was to create an activex control and embed their activex control inside it.  Does anyone know of examples of that begin done or if there is a better solution.

Comment: What Microsoft development environments do you have available to you?  How are you going to register the control on other machines (or is this only going to run on your machine?)

Comment: Im using vs 2005.  It needs to be an active x control that will be registered on a users computer when they navigate to the web page where the active x control resides.

Comment: How many of these classes do you need to use in your webpage?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this would help you as you want to embed it on a web page.

Create a C# control library

under project menu item, select properties

click on assembly information

select 'Make assembly com visible'

click 'okay'

click on build

select 'register for com interop'

then open assemblyinfo.cs and change where it says

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")] to [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")] This way it will ensure that you GUID does not change during each build.

Check these:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dsandor/ActiveXInNet11102005040748AM/ActiveXInNet.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/exposingdotnetcontrols.aspx

Comment: I had already stumbled across those articles earlier in my searching before posting a question here.  I was unable to get those examples working, let alone be able to embed the original activex control.

Comment: I would get this error when trying to run an html page with the embedded activex object. "Automation server can't create object", I then searched for that and tried lowering security settings on IE which also did not work.